# How to count processes of a helper assembly

Tags: c#, counter, .net-assembly

I'm using an helper assembly (HelperAss.) which opens and closes the database connections.

Now Im working in the main assembly (MainAss.) and want to count the database connections which I open (in the MainAssembly). I dont wanna change the HelperAss. because its used by many different people. What would be a clever way to count the opened database connections in the HelperAss. from the MainAssembly (easiest would be counting it directly in the HelperAss. which I want to avoid.)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why is it something you need to know? There are probably way to get that information, but it seems weird you need to get it in a different place than where the connections are established

Comment: How would creating a new method in HelperAss that returns the number of connections interfere with how other people use the assembly?

Comment: the assembly should not be changed, else it does things which it shouldnt in other programs (which also use it).